# JPS command error: malformed host identifier

Tags: java, exception, garbage-collection, cmd, rmi

I found in the JPS command [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html) that we can set the RMI registry port in the host identifier.

I tried the following

`jps XX.XXXX.X.XX:8725`

It returns a weired error:

```
Malformed Host Identifier: XX.XXX.X.XX:8725

usage: jps [-help]

jps [-q] [-mlvV] [<hostid>]

Definitions:

<hostid>:      <hostname>[:<port>]
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key is "< hostname  >" not IP

If I put my IP, I get the same response, but works if I put my host name.